# what happens when .NET Framework is not installed?

Tags: .net, operating-system

Does anyone know what error message will be displayed

when someone tries to run an application developed using .NET

on a computer where .NET Framework is not installed? ex) Windows XP original.

will the error message tell you that .NET Framework is not installed?
or will it not show any useful messages?

Comment: Were you trying to format your question as a poem?

Comment: haha. I was trying to convey the question in a more clear format.
shame it doesn't ryhme.

Comment: Is it possible add a native stub etc. to the .exe, so it will emit a nice, specific error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried running a .NET 2 application on an Windows XP RTM Clone.

I got 2 different errors:

a. The application failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect. Reinstalling the application may fix the problem.

b. Application failed to initialize properly (Some error code)

This suggests that the error thrown is not specific enough to predict.

Comment: Yes and I recently got this message box: http://twitpic.com/1flafq Here, the client framework was installed, but the full was required, somehow...

Answer (score 3):

Here you [go](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316091).

> When you create a .NET application
>   executable (.exe) file, copy the file
>   to a computer on which the .NET
>   Framework is not installed, and then
>   attempt to run the .exe file from that
>   computer, you may receive the
>   following error message (or messages):
>
> **Unable to Locate DLL - The Dynamic Link Library mscoree.dll could not be
>   found in the specified path**.

Comment: This is only for .NET 1/ .NET 1.1